# beautifulsoup: Formatting and conversion issues

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape a web-page however the format within the HTML occasionally changes and is causing problems within my script. The issue I am facing is basically the web page entries are either:

Type 1 :

```
<td>
            &euro;1                       </td>
```

Type 2:

```
<td>
        &euro;12,345         <img src="image1" alt="title" class="flag"/>   
                  </td>
```

I tried removeing the  tag to make the entries transparent however when I convert the entries into a string the Type 1 correctly converts however Type 2 return "None"

I was wondering whether this was due to the '/td>' being on the subsequently lines however I cannot seem to find a solution for this issue. The code which I am using is basically:

```
Dataframe = []    
for Entry in Breakdown:  
   Info = Entry.find_all('td')
   for Price in Info: 
      Detail = Price.string
      Detail_string = str(Price)
      if str(Detail) != 'None':
         Dataframe.append(str(Detail))
```

Where the breakdown consists of the two types of entries which I have shown above and some additional data which is feeding in correctly.

Any help which could be provided to help rectify this issues would be greatly appropriated!
Any more additional information would be happily provided

Comment: you can use the switch case to check the statement type and then execute the script according to your HTML page type. I.e. Type 1 or type 2. Edit: You can also add the `try` and `catch` statement in order to minimize the erros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.get_text(strip=True)` instead of `.string` to get the value inside `<td>`. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<td>
            &euro;1                       </td>
<td>
        &euro;12,345         <img src="image1" alt="title" class="flag"/>   
                  </td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for td in soup.select('td'):
    print(td.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
€1
€12,345
```

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't quite what I expected but set me on the route to my solution.